# WindowsPhone7: How to animate position of UIElement with code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, animation, uielement

It seems like it should be so simple.  I've read dozens of links and I can't get anything to animate the position.  I believe the closest code I can write so far is this:

```
 Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
 TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform() { X = 1.0, Y = 1.0 };
        myCheckbox.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        myCheckbox.RenderTransform = trans;

        DoubleAnimation moveAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
        moveAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1200);
        moveAnim.From = -1;
        moveAnim.To = 1;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(moveAnim, myCheckbox);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(moveAnim, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"));
        storyboard.Completed += new System.EventHandler(storyboard_Completed);
        storyboard.Children.Add(moveAnim);
        storyboard.Begin();
```

No errors are thrown.
The completion callback does get called. 
If I animate opacity in a similar fashion it works fine.

**How can I simply animate a UIElement's position with code??**

Comment: Animating translation from -1 to +1 would be barely perceptible. Have you tried bigger numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment from xyzzer was correct.  The cause of the confusion was because the coordinates for `RenderTransformOrigin` use (0,1) relative to the element.  The actual transforms (e.g. `TranslateTransform`) use pixels as units.